# C:WINDOWSsystem32configsystemprofileAppDataLocalJenkins.jenkinstoolshudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallationmaven/bin/mvn: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, maven, jenkins

I'm running Junkins on a windows machine.
The Jenkins is not reorganizing my maven path

```
     stage('MVN cleanpackage') 
     { 
     def mvnHome = tool name: 'maven', type: 'maven'
     def mvnCMD = "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn"
     sh "${mvnCMD} clean package"
     }
```

Error:
C:WINDOWSsystem32configsystemprofileAppDataLocalJenkins.jenkinstoolshudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallationmaven/bin/mvn clean package
C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Docker-app@tmp/durable-68371c14/script.sh: line 1: *C:WINDOWSsystem32configsystemprofileAppDataLocalJenkins.jenkinstoolshudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallationmaven*/bin/mvn: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the " \ " in your mvnHome value is being interpreted as [Unix escape " \ " characters](https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/escapingsection.html). If running on a Win host, you probably don't want to invoke `"sh"`, which is a Unix shell.

You probably want to configure to [invoke `bat`, not `sh`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/#windows)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I updated the code as below and now i can able to build without any error

```
     stage('MVN cleanpackage') { // for display purposes
     def mvnhome = tool name: 'maven-1', type: 'maven'
     bat "${mvnhome}/bin/mvn clean package"
     }
```